# TPM 2.0 PKCS#11 on Windows and Linux

Tags: tpm, pkcs11

The new Skylake processors have integrated TPM 2.0 inside.

Is there any way how to use the TPM 2.0 as a PKCS#11 token on Windows and Linux for symmetric and asymmetric keys?

TPM 1.2 has a PKCS#11 libraries and I am looking for something similar for TPM 2.0 to use its new RSA keys and certificates hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>- It's a *bit* old question, but I managed to found a solution that worked for me.</sup>

There's available on [Github](https://github.com/irtimmer/tpm2-pk11/) a module that provides PKCS#11 backend for TPM 2.0 chips.

#### Usage:

1. Create TPM Key

   - Create a primary key with hash algorithm sha256 and key algorithm rsa and store the object context in a file (`po.ctx`).

     ```
     tpm2_createprimary -H o -g sha256 -G rsa -C po.ctx
     ```
   - Now create an object that can be loaded into the TPM with parent object from file (`po.ctx`) using hash algorithm SHA256 and key algorithm RSA output the public and private keys to `key.pub|priv`.

     ```
     tpm2_create -c po.ctx -g sha256 -G rsa -u key.pub -r key.priv
     ```
   - Load the private and public keys into the TPM's transient memory.

     ```
     tpm2_load -c po.ctx -u key.pub -r key.priv -C obj.ctx
     ```
   - Make the object persistent, specifying a valid handle.

     ```
     tpm2_evictcontrol -A o -c obj.ctx -H 0x81010010
     ```
   - Now you can remove all temporarily files.

     ```
     rm key.name *.ctx
     ```
2. Install TPM2-PK11 and copy `config.sample` to `~/.tpm2/config`.
3. Create a certificate (eg. w/ Certtool (GnuTLS)).
4. Configure your application to use TPM2-PK11 and the created TPM key.

#### OpenSSH Client:

- Create configuration file and change it for your setup:

  ```
  cp config.sample ~/.tpm2/config
  ```
- Extract public key:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -D libtpm2-pk11.so
  ```
- Use your TPM key:

  ```
  ssh -I libtpm2-pk11.so ssh.example.com
  ```
- or add the PKCS#11 module to your ssh config in `~/.ssh/config`:

  ```
  Host *
      PKCS11Provider libtpm2-pk11.so
  ```

#### Firefox:

- Go to `Preferences`, `Privacy & Security` and click on the button `Security Devices`.
- Press Load and select the `libtpm2-pk11.so` installed on your system.
- After loading the TPM2 PKCS11 Slot should now be listed in the Device Manager and your certificates should be listed when selecting View Certificates under Your Certificates.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative TPM2 PKCS#11 implementation is https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-pkcs11. That's part of the TCG's (Trusted Computing Group's) TSS2 (TPM2 Software Stack), which I believe is intended the be the "official" TPM2 software. As such, I guess "you're supposed to" use this rather than the presumably older tpm2-pk11. In fact, I've seen a presentation (https://events19.linuxfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/TPM-Software-Stack-2018-10-25-final_Peter-Huewe.pdf) that states tpm2-pkcs11 is "Based on PKCS#11 TPM2.0 work by irtimmer" (slide 25).